# VueJs implementing image preview and return incorrect url

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

In `vuejs` i would like to have image preview from what image selected by user, this following code work fine and i can select image but unfortunately after doing this action `reader.readAsDataURL(this.avatar);` return incorrect url for me as `http://localhost/fa/panel/true` and i get `404` error in `console`.

currect url which i show the this form is `http://localhost/fa/panel/user-profile` which that supported with `Laravel` framework.

`html` image and `input` tag

```html
<img v-bind:src="image_preview" width="120" height="120" v-show="show_preview"/>
<input type="file" class="file-styled" name="avatar_path" @change="onFileChange">
```

`vuejs` code:

```js
import {mapGetters, mapMutations} from "vuex";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            avatar: null,
            image_preview: null,
            show_preview: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onFileChange(event) {
            this.avatar = event.target.files[0];
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                console.log(reader.result) // return base-64 of image
                this.image_preview = true;
                this.show_preview = reader.result;
            }.bind(this), false);

            if (this.avatar) {
                if (/\.(jpe?g|png)$/i.test(this.avatar.name)) {
                    console.log(this.avatar); // result is object image
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.avatar);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: this.image_preview = true; -- You forgot to change this to the name? Looks to be the issue to me. Explains why you have /true in your url.

Comment: @JeffB ohhh! i'm so sorry, you right

Comment: Haha no worries! Sometimes it helps just to get an extra set of eyes!